# Problem with Chrome Right-To-Left Paragraphs

Tags: html, google-chrome, right-to-left, packet, paragraph

I've started noticing this **Chrome** problem recently: Some paragraphs inside a table-cell within a right-to-left div - are **randomly** displayed left-to-right. The slower the server, the more it happens (I couldn't reproduce the problem locally), and the problematic paragraphs change upon refreshing the page.

Here is a piece of HTML that demonstrates the issue:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="direction:rtl;">
      <table><tr><td>

<p>
long paragraph
</p><p>
another long paragraph
</p><p>
 . . .
 . . .
</p><p>
last long paragraph
</p>

      </td></tr></table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can see a live demo here: 
http://gioms.com/zzztest.html 
(don't forget to refresh several times)

Any solution to this?

**EDITED:**

The problem is **reproducible**. You still need a server (which may be local), and you can set Chrome to simulate slow connection by using the "Developer tools" (F12) with creating and using a "Throttle" in the "Network" tab / "Online" sub-tab (e.g., 30 Kb/s with 0 latency).

Also no need for an HTML "table".

Apparently the problem occurs in paragraphs on a packet boundary. See https://youtu.be/RG8uO0OqUnY for a video capturing the phenomenon.

Comment: can't reproduce the issue

Comment: Works for me (i.e., I can see the problem) -- Try refreshing and scrolling through the **whole** page, several times...

Comment: I saw it when I switched to a slower wifi network. That's crazy. Have you tried using the html attribute dir="rtl" instead of the `direction` css property? I doubt that will fix it but maybe worth a shot. Is it only in table cells or will other nested elements do this too?

Comment: Yes I tried that and it didn't help. Actually my original problem is worse: My actual website has Hebrew in it (and must have tables), and the random left-to-right paragraphs also reverse the order of letters in the words, which makes it unreadable.

Comment: I've edited the original post with more info.

Comment: @FreeBud can you file a chromium issue about this if there isn't already one and respond here with the issue number? https://crbug.com/new

Comment: You mean something like this? https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/22457926

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this for a few days, I've found a **workaround**, by refreshing all paragraphs locally after everything is loaded:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    function refreshParagraphs() {
      var paragrahpContent;
      var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
      for (i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
        paragrahpContent = paragraphs[i].innerHTML;
        paragraphs[i].innerHTML = paragrahpContent;
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="refreshParagraphs();">
    <div style="direction:rtl;">

<p>
long paragraph
</p><p>
another long paragraph
</p><p>
 . . .
 . . .
</p><p>
last long paragraph
</p>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that refresh corrects the problem, most of the time...