# space make the cursor move weird in text area

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The cursor jumps to the beginning of the RTL sentence whenever I type and press space.
[image]
I saw the same issue in both of the following text-areas

```css
textarea[data-type="alpha"] {
  /* reset: outline, resize */
  /* UI: width, max-height, min-height, background, padding, ... */  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* for scroll bar */
  will-change: transform;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
textarea[data-type="alpha"]::placeholder {
  text-align: right;
}


textarea[data-type="beta"] {
  /* reset: outline, resize */
  /* UI: width, line-height, background, padding, ... */  
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  text-align: right;
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

```html
<textarea 
  data-type="alpha"
  placeholder="Alpha example text"
   
  
  dir="auto" 
  autocapitalize="sentences">
</textarea>


<textarea 
  data-type="beta"
  placeholder="Beta example rtl text"
  dir="auto" 

  maxlength="100">
</textarea>
```

I'm using chrome 89.0.4389.90 on an Android device.
Here is a full reproducible fiddle at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KKTCondition/618u2orz/)

### update

I need the text area to support both RTL and LTR texts, and preferably not determined the direction of texts with js and add `direction: rtl or ltr` to the text area. cause text area may contain both text types at the same time and it will cause e.g. partners to behave oddly.

> Text area is working fine with the LTR texts
> Text area is working fine in the desktop chrome. means that don't change the position of the cursor to the beginning.

Is there a way to fix this?
I guess it is somehow related to chrome updates, but I don't know-how.

Comment: It's working fine for me (as in you've got right justified text that adds to the end of the string in a typical Western character set), but if you're expecting right to left text, then you'll need to set the text direction for right to left text. `direction: rtl;`

Comment: Thank you, yeah in ltr text it works fine @Paul, I want this to support both rtl and ltr, that's why I put the dir="auto"

Comment: Well that will surely depend on the intent for the box - you may have to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to update question

Comment: (Ignore that last comment - I didn't have time to read it all, and it's a bit flakey).

Comment: oh, Come back to a party @Paul

Comment: Hmm.  I can't replicate your issue without switching to Arabic or another RTL configuration in Windows. Have you tried removing the right alignment from the text in the stylesheet?

Comment: yes, as you can see the first textarea (alpha) only put right text-align for its placeholder and it doesn't work too

Comment: I think this might be because of a bug in chrome, as older versions didn't have this problem.

Comment: @MasoudSalehi could be right - I found [this report on Google](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/22457926?hl=en), which does point to [this workaround on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59209306/problem-with-chrome-right-to-left-paragraphs).

Comment: I found another weird behavior happen when using `dir="auto"`, while typing in RTL, whitespaces not affect on the caret until add a letter. tested on `Google Chrome 98.0.4758.80 Linux 64-bit`